# How to create Facebook Fixed Sidebar with Scroll and Overflow for clicked elements using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into an issue. I am creating a simple fixed sidebar (similar to Facebook's sidebar on the right-hand side)

In Facebook when you interact with the sidebar 2 things happen

1. A scrollbar appears when the contents need to be scrolled
2. When you hover or click a name a popover appears to the left

I am having an issue with the popover conflict with overflow. As from what I understand to get the sidebar to scroll the overflow must be set to scroll on the parent div, this hiding any elements appearing outside of it.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to build my sidebar and have created a JSFiddle here of a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/bNFAf/5/

The problem with my example is that when I click on the Icon `<i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i>` to activate the `dropdown-menu`, it gets cut off due to the overflow set on the `#sidebar` div.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this working? If possible to do without jQuery and just CSS, great! Otherwise, jQuery could work.

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/bNFAf/5/

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNFAf/3/). As far as the scroll bars go, there are more elegant was to implement custom scrollbars. Check them out. and the sidebar is rendering the options list in the same div. So unless you write custom logic to implement that div outside the sidebar container, there is not much to edit on this.

Comment: hey man, thanks but that solution just widens my sidebar to fit in the dropdown which won't work for me. I need it to appear over it like it works in Facebook...

Comment: You want the options sub list to appear over the main list or do you want a new div to be created next to the scroll bar? Of how you want it to look, provide a diagrammatic representation.

Comment: @Shouvik, I want the sublist to appear over the main list in it's current position. A bit like a context menu would. For example, in my JSFiddle above you can change the CSS by removing #sidebar:hover and you will see the menu appearing fine (just now I can't scroll the main list) does that make sense?

Comment: I am sorry, I can't exactly understand. [This is what I have now](http://jsfiddle.net/bNFAf/9/). How would you like this to change?

Comment: yeah I see you just moved the margin-left for the dropdown back inside the div. THat works of course but not what i want. The dropdown needs to stay in that position where I have it. margin-left: 260px

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26180/discussion-between-shouvik-and-redwall)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNFAf/10/)

This uses bootstrap popover it allows for positioning left so that the options fly out over the menu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.icon-cog').popover({
    placement: 'left',
    html: 'true',
    trigger: 'click',
    container: 'body'    
});

});
```

You could use [JQuery Drill Down Ipod Menu](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-jquery-drill-down-ipod-menu-widget/)

Comment: Hi thanks, yeah I wanted to use the dropdown as that builds out menu's and submenus. The popover can just take html and everything would be needed to be built from scratch within a menu using JS and that would not be feasible. thanks anyway